# How to stop Twisted callback?

Tags: python, twisted, autobahn, twisted.web, twisted.internet

I wrote a callback function using twisted Now my question is when websocket connection dropped I need to stop this callback.

```
def sendBack(self, payload):
    # find correct way to identify connection dropped now using wasnotcl...
    if self.wasNotCleanReason:
        # stop this callback
    self.sendMessage("Message")
    reactor.callLater(delay, self.sendBack, payload=payload)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `cancel` it...

```
callID = reactor.callLater(delay, self.sendBack, payload=payload)
    if self.wasNotCleanReason:
        callID.cancel()
```

`ref`